# 2 questions about RESTful Web Services

Tags: java, rest, service, web

I am new to RESTful web services.  I have the following 2 questions:

1. Are GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, TRACE, HEAD, OPTIONS, the only verbs in Http that I can use for RESTful web services?
2. How do I create and use a custom verb?

I'm using Java and Jersey for creating my RESTful web services.

Comment: What possible verb could you need beyond GET, POST, PUT and DELETE?  Please explain.

Comment: going outside the HTTP specification by creating custom verbs will make your service non HTTP-compliant which could cause unforseen problems down the road (e.g. interoperability). Also, most developers will never go beyond GET and POST, so it would be interesting to know why you think you need something new

Comment: To be honest, I'm new to web services.  So, I probably have a great deal of misconceptions about it.  But suppose I want to provide 10 different actions.  Then how do I provide the 10 actions with only 7 verbs?  Doesn't each action go under a separate verb? Or I'm wrong and can use conditionals to provide several actions under a single verb?

In general how do others design their application such that they don't need extra verbs even if they need to provide a 100 different actions?

Comment: See my answer, you don't want to use HTTP request methods (GET, POST, ETC) to define the "verbs" in your app. Think of these as something lower level, like sending and receiving.

Comment: [§5.1.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-5.1.1): You can define your own HTTP methods without going outside the HTTP specification, so it still would be techincally HTTP-compliant. Although your interoperability comments still apply.

Comment: Please **update** the question with "But suppose I want to provide 10 different actions..." and all that follows.  This is part of the question.  Not a comment.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to question 1 is, yes as they are restricted by the HTTP specification. However as a matter of practice, most REST applications use only GET and POST, as these are most widely supported by all of the Internet infrastructure. And then the answer to question two is no, you can't create a custom verb.

The thing you have to consider in your use of the HTTP verbs is that a GET should have no side effects, as the client is free to resend a GET at any time (in the event a communication failure was detected). A POST however can be sent by the client at most once, so this should be used for anything that causes a change that cannot be repeated (like an insert).

Normally you would define what "verb" you want in your application as part of the URL, not as the HTTP verb.

Comment: I can think of no reason for you to "add" a verb.  At the very least you will make it challenging for your clients to use many of the frameworks out there for making webservice calls as these frameworks are built around the standard HTTP verbs.  If you get the time and you want to really learn what HTTP can do for you, I strongly recommend reading "REST in Practice: Hypermedia and Systems Architecture" by Jim Webber, Savas Parastatidis, and Ian Robinson.  I didn't really know HTTP until I worked through this book.

Answer (score 0):

> Then how do I provide the 10 actions with only 7 verbs?

The idea behind web services is to focus on the **objects**, not the verbs.

Your actions either "Create" ("POST"), "Retrieve" ("GET"), "Update" ("PUT") or "Remove" ("DELETE") the **objects**.

> Doesn't each action go under a separate verb?

No.  You can have all the objects you want.  You only need four verbs to create, find, change and remove objects.

> Or I'm wrong and can use conditionals to provide several actions under a single verb?

No.  You can make a  create ("POST") request which can, in turn, create a number of individual objects.

> In general how do others design their application such that they don't need extra verbs even if they need to provide a 100 different actions?

You focus on the **objects**.  Objects are created, retrieved, updated and deleted.